# Fragmento en html, texto al pasar mouse

Tags: html

¿Se puede ajustar el texto a un cuadro tipo ?

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
<div class='about' title='cuadro de varios caracteres'>imagen</div>
```

Estoy exagerando en la cantidad de letras pero si son muchas necesito hacer que eso se vea en un cuadrito por ejemplo en este se vea en 50x50 un cuadrito que yo personalice osea el `title`. ¿Será esto posible?

Answer (score 1):

Hola te mando esta referencia, esta basado en eventos con el mouse con jquery y con el atributo title de la imagen, si juegas un poco con el código podrás adaptarlo a tu código, cualquier duda puedes preguntarme y con gusto te la aclaro. saludos.

```js
$('.myImg').hover(function(){
   txt = $(this).attr('title');
   $(this).removeAttr('title');
   $('.tooltip').append(txt);
   $('.tooltip').show();
  });

  $('.myImg').mouseleave(function(){
   txt = $('.tooltip').text();
   $('.myImg').attr('title',txt);
   $('.tooltip').empty();
   $('.tooltip').hide();
  });

  $('.tooltip').hide();
```

```css
.wrap{
   float: left;
   padding: 10px;
   background: #ccc;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   overflow: hidden;
  }

  .wrap img{
   width: 190px;
   float: left;
  }

  .tooltip{
   width: 150px;
   height: 150px;
   background: #FF6;
   float: left;
   font-size: 12px;
   padding: 5px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">

  <img class="myImg" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque ex mauris, mattis vel lobortis id, congue in neque. Curabitur bibendum eu urna non ullamcorper. Nam et tortor gravida, commodo eros vel, laoreet enim." src="https://res.cloudinary.com/factra/image/upload/v1517506621/eeenwubouhshpz0wu5g1.jpg">

  
 </div>

 <div class="tooltip">
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

la solución, sería basicamente generar tu propio cuadrito.
Te dejo un ejemplo aca:

HTML.

```
<div href="#" class="tip">imagen<span>cuadro de varios caracteres</span></a>
```

CSS.

```
a.tip {
    border-bottom: 1px dashed;
    text-decoration: none
}
a.tip:hover {
    cursor: help;
    position: relative
}
a.tip span {
    display: none
}
a.tip:hover span {
    border: #c0c0c0 1px dotted;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 5px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 100;
    left: 0px;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    text-decoration: none
}
```